# Ubuntu 22.04 starts very slowly on 27"MAC

Tags: 22.04

I installed Ubuntu 22.04  on a Mac 27" late(2015) 5k
It takes 45 seconds to come out of sleep and 5 minutes to boot up. There are no problems once it is running.

```
1min 23.148s apt-daily.service

 1min 9.573s setvtrgb.service

     50.016s snapd.seeded.service
     49.129s upower.service
     30.760s plymouth-quit-wait.service1
     17.288s snapd.service
      9.339s colord.service
      7.763s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      2.527s fwupd.service
      1.449s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      1.151s networkd-dispatcher.service
       933ms mysql.service
       730ms ua-timer.service
       689ms dev-loop8.device
       687ms dev-loop18.device
       684ms dev-loop13.device
       684ms dev-loop9.device
       684ms dev-loop14.device
       684ms dev-loop10.device
       682ms dev-loop11.device
       681ms dev-loop12.device
       677ms dev-loop19.device
       618ms dev-loop15.device
       618ms dev-loop16.device
       615ms dev-loop17.device
       444ms dev-loop5.device
       444ms dev-loop6.device
       444ms dev-loop7.device
       417ms man-db.service
       414ms dev-sda2.device
       404ms dev-loop4.device
       333ms dev-loop2.device
       329ms dev-loop3.device
       311ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       253ms logrotate.service
       177ms phpsessionclean.service
       174ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       166ms apparmor.service
       146ms udisks2.service
       131ms systemd-resolved.service
       126ms accounts-daemon.service
       118ms snapd.apparmor.service
       113ms systemd-logind.service
       110ms modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service
       102ms systemd-modules-load.service
        97ms dev-loop1.device
        97ms apache2.service
        96ms systemd-oomd.service
        96ms ModemManager.service
        95ms systemd-timesyncd.service
        94ms e2scrub_reap.service
        94ms dev-loop0.device
        90ms user@1000.service
        90ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        87ms modprobe@mtdpstore.service
        85ms bluetooth.service
        82ms systemd-rfkill.service
        72ms systemd-udevd.service
        71ms power-profiles-daemon.service
        71ms plymouth-read-write.service
        66ms keyboard-setup.service1
        65ms update-notifier-download.service
        64ms NetworkManager.service
        62ms systemd-journald.service
        61ms boot-efi.mount
        60ms ufw.service
        59ms gdm.service
        57ms avahi-daemon.service
        52ms apport.service
        51ms polkit.service
        48ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
        47ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-03E4\x2d1EB4.service
        42ms grub-common.service
        40ms console-setup.service
        39ms gpu-manager.service
        39ms switcheroo-control.service
        38ms packagekit.service
        36ms snap-bare-5.mount
        36ms thermald.service
        35ms fwupd-refresh.service
        34ms snap-core18-2409.mount
        34ms snap-core20-1494.mount
        33ms snap-core20-1518.mount
        33ms bolt.service
        32ms wpa_supplicant.service
        32ms snap-firefox-1539.mount
        31ms snap-firefox-1551.mount
        30ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-106.mount
        30ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-112.mount
        29ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-920.mount
        28ms snap-gnome\x2dclocks-446.mount
        27ms systemd-sysusers.service
        27ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1534.mount
        26ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
        26ms systemd-random-seed.service
        25ms snap-snap\x2dstore-575.mount
        25ms snap-snap\x2dstore-582.mount
        24ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
        24ms snap-snapd-16010.mount
        23ms snap-snapd-16292.mount
        22ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-10.mount
        21ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-14.mount
        21ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        20ms snap-sublime\x2dtext-112.mount
        20ms snap-vlc-2344.mount
        16ms plymouth-start.service
        15ms rsyslog.service
        15ms cups.service
        14ms dev-hugepages.mount
        14ms dev-mqueue.mount
        13ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
        13ms modprobe@drm.service
        13ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
        11ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        11ms kmod-static-nodes.service
        10ms modprobe@ramoops.service
        10ms modprobe@configfs.service
         9ms systemd-remount-fs.service
         9ms modprobe@fuse.service
         7ms kerneloops.service
         7ms systemd-sysctl.service
         7ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
         6ms dpkg-db-backup.service
         6ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
         6ms alsa-restore.service
         6ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
         4ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         4ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
         3ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         3ms modprobe@pstore_zone.service
         3ms openvpn.service
         3ms motd-news.service
         2ms rtkit-daemon.service
         2ms modprobe@pstore_blk.service
         2ms systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl0.service
         2ms swapfile.swap
         2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         2ms sys-kernel-config.mount
       586us snapd.socket
```

Comment: copy/paste/run this `systemd-analyze blame` in the terminal and you will show you what is causing the long boot time if it isn't a hardware related problem.

Comment: It seems that there is now hardware-acceleration for graphics at this time.
Is snap working/getting updates? Whats the output of 'sudo snap refresh'

Comment: It’s likely to be driver related. Looking at verbose logs may guide you to which driver. As well as looking at the specific device you’re using to wake it and any hardware items not listed as Ubuntu certified. It could be related to a mouse you’re using to wake the device, as an example. Issues that are fixed or created from a kernel change are often related to driver support in the end.

Comment: All snaps are up to date

Comment: Wordpress is working and python3

Comment: Ran systems-analysis on my raspberry pi4 with Ubuntu 22.04 and apt-daily.service and setvtrgb.service was not running